# Not able to Convert Rest Response To a List<MyClass> using Rest Easy Client

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jackson, resteasy

I have to call a REST WS which can return any JSON structure out of which I want only **id** and **name** which every Service will return. The code which I wrote is:-  
`

```
public class RestWebServiceCaller {
public static <T> ArrayList<T> callGETRestWebService(String url,String mediaType, Class<T> responseType) throws Exception {
    ClientRequest request=new ClientRequest(url);
    request.accept(mediaType);
    ClientResponse<T> response=request.get(responseType);
    return (ArrayList<T>)response.getEntity();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ArrayList<ScopeResponse> response=callGETRestWebService("http://10.63.8.220:9080/get",MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
                ,ScopeResponse.class);
        ArrayList<ScopeResponse> scope=(ArrayList<ScopeResponse>) response;
        System.out.println(scope.get(0).getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ScopeResponse {
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}
But this line **System.out.println(scope.get(0).getName());** is giving Class cast Exception.
My Requirement is to have a Custom class(with Id and Name properties) which can convert every Rest call to the List.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you expecting a JSON array?

Comment: @peeskillet I want to have a Generic API which calls any Rest service and i am able to fetch the Response as a List<MyClass> and parse it. But one Rest Service is returning a Map so when i am trying to get the Name it is giving Class Cast Exception.

Comment: You can't expect a Map to be converted to a List. Doesn't work like that. A Map is a JSON object. A List is a JSON array. You need to decide which one you want to use. If you are expecting a JSON object, then you should be trying to get a Map, not a List.

Comment: @peeskillet ok...thanks..I was thinking to have a Generic One which supports all but seems it is not possible as u said.